# Unable to login to 14.04 after successful installation

Tags: upgrade, login, 14.04, login-screen

After a successful upgrade to 14.04, now when I am trying to login using administrator id, It loops back to login page and doesn't load my session. Even guest is not working.
When I enter wrong password for administrator, it shows invalid password label.

File name ~/.xsession-errors show below error

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Script for ibus started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
```

Please let me know what should I do.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the exact same symptoms and the "duplicate" answer is not working.

Answer (score -1):

After upgrade to 14.04, I had changed the driver to NVIDIA proprietary for my GF119M [GeForce 610M] graphics card which was causing this issue.

I had to do a fresh installation of 14.04 and this time I continued with driver X.Org X Server (Open Source) from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau.

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the `~/.Xauthority` file then rebooting solved my issue.